# site doesnt load resources

Tags: java, html, css, spring

I tried to add a login stuff but then the whole thing stopped working correctly. What i mean is:

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/login' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I spent like 3hours on this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"     xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">

<head>
<title>Logging </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="loginStyle.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="image-bg">
<div class="login">
  <div class="allarms">
    <div th:if="${param.error}">
     Wrong password
    </div>
    <div th:if="${param.logout}">
      Logged out
    </div>
  </div>
  <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post" id="form-login">
    <div><label> User : <input type="text" name="username" />         
     </label></div>
    <div><label> Password <input type="password" name="password" /> </label>    
  </div>
    <div id="input-login"><input type="submit" value="Log in" /></div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my css file:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.image-bg {
  background-image: url("bgimage.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 900px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
}

.login {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.login .form-login {
  padding: 5px;
}

.login .allarms {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

PS

Something wierd happend... I've added a new html file with new css file and old error came back to this new HTML file - lol? I get this error:

Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

But old HTML files load css files correctly.

Comment: Help me, please :/

Answer (score 0):

If you use inspector within your browser, does it show any errors? 
If you check the Network tab, do you see any files being loaded in?
I see you're using spring security, did you permit your resources to be loaded by all?

Comment: This is it because when i remove:

    .anyRequest().authenticated()

from web security config everything is working fine. I made it like this:

    .antMatchers("/", "/showAllCats", "/showAllDogs","/resources/**").permitAll()

but with no succes. Still resources are not loading.

Comment: Ok, man, thank you for help. I didnt have a clue that Spring Security blocks resources :) I resolved it by adding sites that i wanna block with logging to .antMatches("**** STRINGS ****).authenticated()